# Validate json format in prestoDB

Tags: json, presto

We use presto JSON capabilities quit heavily and on thing the is missing for us is to be able to null when JSON is not a valid on this way SQL statement that use JSON functions will not break if there is a problem with the JSON format.

Initially I thought it can be done with some combination of `JSON_PARSE` and `NULLIF` but couldn't manage to pull this of..
is there a way to do make this kind of validation?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try) function to prevent the json functions from failing the query.  For example, `SELECT try(json_parse('bad json'))` will return `null` instead of failing the query.